# Oracle 12c, export table with sequence as default value, schema is attached

Tags: oracle, sequence, oracle12c, default-value

I'm use oracle 12c with a user u1. With user u1 I create table T1 like this,

```
create SEQUENCE  T1_SEQ START WITH  1;
CREATE  table T1(
  id number(11) DEFAULT T1_SEQ.nextval PRIMARY KEY ,
  name varchar2(255)
);
```

Now I want to export the schema to others, and use below command to export

```
expdp u1/password dumpfile=u1.dmp  schemas=u1
```

, but when others use u1.dmp to import the schema with a new user named u2,

```
impdp u2/password   remap_schema=u1:u2  DUMPFILE=u1.DMP TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE
```

error happend, beacause default value of table T1 column id add U1 as prefix.

```
U1.T1_SEQ.nextval
```

and here is the new create table statement

```
CREATE  table T1(
      id number(11) DEFAULT U1.T1_SEQ.nextval PRIMARY KEY ,
      name varchar2(255)
    );
```

How can I remove the U1's influence while I want to move one schema to  another schema.
Could you give me some suggestions? Thanks in advance!.

Comment: As you're on 12c why not use IDENTITY column instead?

Comment: Certainly identity is more proper, but my team has used default sequence on some old tables in our projiect for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a known and ongoing issue according to Ask Tom.

So You can,

1. excluding the affected objects from the import
2. using the sqlfile option to import the affected objects
3. amending the sqlfile script output to point to the correct objects before running it

[Please See relevant topic](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9533916100346734356)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll do as what you said for the next time when we do need a different schme, at present we use the same schema to avoid the problem.